# When I open the Excel it runs the macro and change the date saved

Tags: excel, vba, date, checkbox

Am doing a macro in a check box (Form Control), the main idea is when I check the check box in the next cell it saves the date of the day I marked the checkbox. But instead if I save the check box with the mark it gets updated when I open the document, erasing the saved date and updating today's date.

I've tried 2 `ifs` and `Errors GoTo Err` and doesn't work

this is the code I have:

```
If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 2").ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then

cells(6, 5).Value = Date

Else

 Range("E6").ClearContents

End If
```

I need to put some code that stops the actualization. Or it tells the macro that when the check box is mark doesn't have to update the date.

Comment: Not sure what's the real question here... Your code is trying to set a date when the checkbox is marked, but your comment is seeking otherwise...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the intent is to store the date of last marking the checkbox you could simply make a value copy, a very basic example:

```
Sub CheckBox1_Click()

'cell A1 = linked cell to check box
'Cell A2 contains formula today()
'cell A3 target cell overwritten on marking check box

Select Case Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

Case True

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Select

End Sub
```